# Writing Functor instance vs. writing Eq instance for NonEmpty in Purescript

Tags: class, types, functor, purescript

I'm currently learning Purescript by reading the [Purescript by Example](https://leanpub.com/purescript/read) book (so far one of the only resources I've found that covers the language extensively).

I'm trying to implement the exercises in section 6.7 (Instance Dependencies), and I can't get my head around the following compiler error:

[image]

I've implemented the Semigroup and Eq instances for a data type `data NonEmpty a = NonEmpty a (Array a)` as follows:

```
instance eqNonEmpty :: Eq a => Eq (NonEmpty a) where
  eq (NonEmpty h1 t1) (NonEmpty h2 t2) = h1 == h2 && t1 == t2


instance semigroupNonEmpty :: Semigroup (NonEmpty a) where
  append (NonEmpty h1 t1) (NonEmpty h2 t2) = NonEmpty h1 (t1 <> [h2] <> t2)
```

But when I try to implement the Functor instance the same way I get the error above.
What seems to work is this:

```
instance functorNonEmpty :: Functor NonEmpty where
  map f (NonEmpty h t) = NonEmpty (f h) (map f t)
```

Now, why is that? I can't figure it out.
Thanks!

Comment: Coupla suggestions: The 'official' version of the book is out of date. This fork is the most up-to-date: https://github.com/dwhitney/purescript-book/ . Also, PureScript syntax is so similar to Haskell that I've found it easy to use Haskell books to learn quite a lot of PureScript. I found Haskell Programming From First Principles to be very thorough, and I solved most of the exercises in PureScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's just how the `Functor` class is defined: it applies to types that take a parameter. So, for example, the `Functor` class would apply to `Maybe` and to `List`, but wouldn't apply to `Int` or to `String`, and equally wouldn't apply to `Maybe Int` or `List String`.

The type `NonEmpty` does take a parameter, because that's how it is defined:

```
data NonEmpty a = ...
```

But a type `NonEmpty a` does *not* take a parameter, regardless of what `a` might be.

The classes `Eq` and `Semigroup`, on the other hand, expect a type without any parameters. So these classes can apply to `Int`, `String`, `Maybe Boolean`, and any other type without parameters, including `NonEmpty a`, regardless of what `a` might be.

Comment: Thanks Fyodor! That's a very good concise and clear explanation. I'd love to have a little more insight on how to infer this from the type signature itself for other cases. Is it because of the  `f a` and `f b` in the `map :: ..` definition inside Functor where it says `forall a b. (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` that you can infer that?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sometimes there may also be an explicit kind signature, like `class Functor (f :: Type -> Type)`. This may be required in cases where the compiler can't infer the kind from usage like it does from `f a`.